# Current Skin Url

Tags: magento-1, theme, skin

I want to get skin URL of my current theme. At present I am working in Magento "rwd" theme.

And I am using below code to get skin URL:

```
Mage::getDesign()->getSkinUrl();
```

This returns me URL http://localhost/magento/skin/frontend/default/default/

but I need URL like: http://localhost/magento/skin/frontend/rwd/default/

Please help me.

Comment: the above code works fine for me , check in the backend you assigned correctly

Comment: Are you calling any file at all?

Comment: At backend I am setting rwd theme in design.But no effect in this function.

Comment: @AdarshKhatri  I am calling this function in php file

Comment: I meant, any css js img file? Could you add your full code how you are calling and where?

Comment: I am not adding any css or js file in my file.FYI : This is located in model/file.php

Comment: which Magento version are you using? Do you have any design overrides?

Comment: This should work, if it is really called when the *current store* has the `rwd` package configured. Check, what `Mage::getDesign()->getStore()->getCode()` and `Mage::getDesign()->getPackagename()` return.

Answer (score 43):

I have used following command to get different URL in magento
Get Url in phtml files

**1. Get Base Url :**

```
Mage::getBaseUrl();
```

**2. Get Skin Url :**

```
Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_SKIN);
```

**(a) Unsecure Skin Url :**

```
$this->getSkinUrl('images/imagename.jpg');
```

**(b) Secure Skin Url :**

```
$this->getSkinUrl('images/imagename.gif', array('_secure'=>true));
```

**3. Get Media Url :**

```
Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
```

**4. Get Js Url :**

```
Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_JS);
```

**5. Get Store Url :**

```
Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);
```

**6. Get Current Url**

```
Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
```

**Get Url in cms pages or static blocks**

**1. Get Base Url** :

```
{{store url=""}}
```

**2. Get Skin Url** :

```
{{skin url='images/imagename.jpg'}}
```

**3. Get Media Url :**

```
{{media url='/imagename.jpg'}}
```

**4. Get Store Url :**

```
{{store url='mypage.html'}}
```

I think this will help you.

Comment: Please explain, in which context you call `$this->getSkinUrl()` - i.e. what is `$this`?. The rest is a nice list, but irrelevant to OPs question

Comment: You can use : Mage::getBaseUrl('skin').'/frontend/default/mytheme/';

Comment: `$this` is the block in this context. e.g., if you are rendering the current template using following code `<block type="core/template" name="my_block" template="page/html/my_template.phtml" />`, `$this` in the phtml file will refer to a block of type `Mage_Core_Block_Template`

Comment: Note that getSkinUrl accepts parameters. So you can do for example: `{{skin url="imagename.jpg" _package="mypackage" _theme="default" _area="frontend"}}`. 
More at \Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package::getSkinUrl.

Answer (score 6):

You can easily avail the current URL of your existing Magento theme by using the below-mentioned code:

```
<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl();?>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are using

```
Mage::getDesign()->getSkinUrl($file = null, array $params = array());
```

You should pass in the `$file` parameter for the resource you are trying to retrieve; e.g.:

```
Mage::getDesign()->getSkinUrl('images/example.png');
```

Magento will automatically search in your site's set theme first and if it's not there it will continue its search using the [theme fallback](https://www.classyllama.com/blog/depth-look-magento-theme-fallback).

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you default theme is default and rwd theme do not have requested image.

Comment: this is my case, thank you